# Send Mail from ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

in my application i m sending a mail from gmail server. when i m executing the code its giving error

here is the code

```
    mail.To.Add(txtTo.Text);
    mail.From = new MailAddress(txtFrom.Text);
    mail.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
    mail.Body = txtBody.Text;
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
          mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream,        FileUpload1.FileName));
    }
     SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
     smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; 
     smtp.Port = 587;
     smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

     smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential
         ("my gmail ID", "my password");

    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.Send(mail);
```

After execution i m getting below error

```
    Message : -  "Failure sending mail."
   Inner Exception : - {"Unable to connect to the remote server"}
```

please have a look.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677258/send-email-using-system-net-mail-through-gmail-c#4677382

Answer (score 0):

> Inner Exception : - {"Unable to
>   connect to the remote server"}

Check your firewall settings.

Also, are you using a shared hosting? Host shared hostings (at least the ones I know) do not allow you to do socket communication. Some allow it when you get dedicated IP.