# SMTP Email Sending

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp

No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:25
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

> Exception Details:
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No
>   connection could be made because the
>   target machine actively refused it
>   127.0.0.1:25

Source Error:

> An unhandled exception was
>   generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information
>   regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using
>   the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [SocketException (0x274d): No
>   connection could be made because the
>   target machine actively refused it
>   127.0.0.1:25]    System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint
>   endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress
>   socketAddress) +239
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalConnect(EndPoint
>   remoteEP) +35
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean
>   connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6,
>   Socket& socket, IPAddress& address,
>   ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception&
>   exception) +224
>
> [WebException: Unable to connect to
>   the remote server]
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream
>   PooledStream, Object owner, Boolean
>   async, IPAddress& address, Socket&
>   abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket6,
>   Int32 timeout) +5483819
>   System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object
>   owningObject, Boolean async, Int32
>   timeout, GeneralAsyncDelegate
>   asyncCallback) +202
>   System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object
>   owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate
>   asyncCallback) +21
>   System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object
>   owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate
>   asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout)
>   +332    System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(String
>   host, Int32 port) +160
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(String
>   host, Int32 port) +159
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()
>   +35    System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage
>   message) +1213
>
> [SmtpException: Failure sending mail.]
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage
>   message) +1531
>   Checkout.btnSend_Click(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) +2675
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs
>   e) +111
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +110
>   I can't send email in live connection but in my local its working.

please help me guys.

> System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +10
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument)
>   +13    System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection
>   postData) +36
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1565

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3615; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3618

here's my C# code..

```
        SmtpClient SmtpMail = new SmtpClient();
        SmtpMail.Host = "localhost";

        //delete session cookie
        Response.Cookies["session"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-30);

        SmtpMail.Send(objEmail);
```

Comment: Is there even a mail server on your machine? Did you try to `telnet localhost 25`?

Comment: What SMTP server are you using?

Comment: ...and don't forget to check your (windows) firewall...

Comment: ... and is your local host configured as an SMTP server?

Comment: You also may have to provide some authentication. And are you sure  you want to mail from localhost?

Comment: @m0sa: firewalls typically swallow packets silently, so you tend to get timeouts rather than actively refused connections.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You forgot to start your SMTP server on that machine

Please don't tell you don't have a SMTP server on that machine. But, if you have to tell that, refer to this [page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308161) and [this](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/e4cf06f5-9a36-474b-ba78-3f287a2b88f2.mspx?mfr=true) page also

Even if you configure the local SMTP server, your emails are most likely to end up in spam folder. Better use the SMTP server of your email provider. If you are using Gmail, have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677258/send-email-using-system-net-mail-through-gmail-c/4677382#4677382)

Comment: Yeah but in my case I get this same 127.0.0.1:25 error, despite the SMTP service being on, despite SMTP server being on and functional. It was working before but suddenly stopped due to maybe some sort of security setting change (but not settings in SMTP).

Answer (score 2):

I got the error with smtp services installed but not started. To start services on the local machine with smtp already installed, here's the steps I took:

1. Open *Server Manager*
2. Select *Local Server*
3. Type "smtp" in the filter box under *SERVICES* (see image)
4. Right click on *Simple Mail Transfer Protocol Service (SMTP)* and
   select *Start Services*

[image: Server manager with Local Server selected and services filtered to smtp]

Comment: This worked for me. But I had to set the startup type to automatic since it was on manual for some reason...

Comment: @VDWWD I actually just had to do the same thing this week.