# Sending hardcoded email with attachment

Tags: c#, email-attachments, mailmessage, hardcode

I am trying to write a code for sending hard coded email with attachment i-e I don't want to use the buttons and text fields. I want when the program runs it should automatically go to location in my drive and attach some files and email it to the email address which I have already told that program while coding.

The normal code with buttons and text fields does not work. See below the normal code

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from.Text, to.Text, subject.Text, body.Text);
mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(attachment1.Text));

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(smtp.Text);
client.Port = 587;
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username.Text, password.Text);
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Send(mail);
MessageBox.Show("Mail Sent!", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
```

I have tried replacing `from.Text`, `to.Text`, `subject.Text`, `body.Text` and `attachment1.Text` with a string as

```
string from="abc@gmail.com";
string attachment1=@"c:\image1.jpg";
```

They give me errors.

Comment: What, specifically, is the error(s) you are seeing? Have you tried disabling SSL? (The mail server may not be configured to use SSL) Also, be sure that the TO and FROM addresses are valid addresses.

Comment: Need the exact error really..

Comment: Are you using gmail for the smtp server? if you are you might want to check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677258/send-email-using-system-net-mail-through-gmail-c

Comment: mail.Attachments.Add(data);

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `.Text` after each variable, as strings don't have a `Text` property.

Like this:

`MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, body);`