# Set up sender account to my Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem from my WPF Project

Tags: c#, wpf, outlook, office-interop

I have a WPF C # project where I have a function to send emails, with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem but I don't know how to configure the ***sender account***, it is a **gmail account**, and I don't know how to tell it or how to give it the ***username*** and ***password*** of it, can someone guide me?

```
public void sendEMailThroughOUTLOOK(string PDFAdjunto, string XMLAdjunto, string from, string[] to, string subject, string body, string cc)
{
    try
    {            
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
        // Create a new mail item.
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

        // add to's
        if (to[0] != string.Empty && to[0] != null)
        {
            oMsg.Recipients.Add(to[0]);
        }
        if (to[1] != string.Empty && to[1] != null)
        {
            oMsg.Recipients.Add(to[1]);
        }

        // Mail body
        oMsg.Body = body;
        oMsg.BodyFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatPlain;

        // Mail attachments
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Attachment oAttach1 = oMsg.Attachments.Add(XMLAdjunto);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Attachment oAttach2 = oMsg.Attachments.Add(PDFAdjunto);

        // Mail subject
        oMsg.Subject = subject;

        // Resolve accounts
        oMsg.Recipients.ResolveAll();

        // Send mail
        ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem)oMsg).Send();

        // Clean up.
        oMsg = null;
        oApp = null;
    }
    catch (System.Exception e) 
    {
        Mensaje = new wMensaje("Error en envío de Mail", DateTime.Now.ToString()
            + System.Environment.NewLine + subject
            + System.Environment.NewLine + " De: '" + from + "' "
            + System.Environment.NewLine + " Para: '" + to[0] + "', '" + to[1] + "' '"
            + (e.Message.Contains("Operación anulada") ? System.Environment.NewLine + System.Environment.NewLine + "-->  Asegúrese de tener ABIERTO su Outlook  <--" : "")
            + System.Environment.NewLine + System.Environment.NewLine + " Error: "
        + System.Environment.NewLine + System.Environment.NewLine
        + (e.InnerException == null ? e.Message : e.InnerException.ToString()));
        Mensaje.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know how to configure the sender account, it is a gmail account, and I don't know how to tell it or how to give it the username and password of it

You can use the [MailItem.SendUsingAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sendusingaccount) property which returns or sets an `Account` object that represents the account under which the `MailItem` is to be sent. The `SendUsingAccount` property can be used to specify the account that should be used to send the `MailItem` when the `Send` method is called. This property returns `Null` (`Nothing` in Visual Basic) if the account specified for the `MailItem` no longer exists.

Note, to be able to set up the `SendUsingAccount` property it must be configured in the Outlook profile.

---

You may also consider using the `System.Net.Mail` namespace, read more about that in the [Send email using System.Net.Mail through gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677258/send-email-using-system-net-mail-through-gmail) article.

Comment: ok, I'm understanding, I must have de Outlook open with the account that I want to use for sent the message from my app? what about if i have the user and password account? I can't set it, and declare it, in the function into my project?

Comment: No, the Outlook object model doesn't provide to specify the username and password of the account to send from. You need to configure this account in Outlook or delegate permissions to send on behalf of.

Comment: Thank you Eugene Astafiev I took your suggestion with .Net.Mail