# Sending mail .netcore

Tags: c#

Sending mail using .netcore 3.1 and kafka

Comment: I don't get what your question has to do with Kafka. You just want to send email from a .NET app. What's stopping you?

Comment: i want to send it using kafka producer and consumer

Comment: do you have a suggestion that I would like to do something in the structure that you see on the link @mason

Comment: I don't see any point in looking at the link. You want to send an email from .NET. That issue has nothing to do with Kafka. Try that out. See if you can get it working. Then if you need it to happen in the context of a Kafka consumer, then put the code there. If it doesn't work, provide a [mcve].

Comment: All right, I'll try. Thank you very much @mason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka doesn't use SMTP protocol.

If you want a producer to get data to an email client, you'd need to consume a record, then use some other library to send emails.

```
// TODO: create consumer
// TODO: loop over records

var consumeResult = consumer.Consume(...);

//  TODO: Define this method
sendMail(consumeResult.Message);

// TODO: handle exceptions and close consumer when done
```

For example - [Send email using System.Net.Mail through gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677258/send-email-using-system-net-mail-through-gmail)